# Heatmap Fill empty spaces with black

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Suppose this is the data at hand:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import seaborn as sns


data = {'trajectory': [101,102,102,102,102,102,102,102,104,104,104,104,104,104,104,107,107,107,107,
          107,107,107,107,107,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,109,109,109,109,109,109,112,
         112,112,112,112,113,113,113,113,114,114,114,114],
 'segment': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,
          2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2],
  'prediction': [3,0,0,1,3,3,2,2,0,0,4,4,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,
          1,1,0,1,2,1,3,3,3,1,1,4,4,2,1,4,4,3,0,3,3,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head(2)
    trajectory  segment prediction
0      101        1       3
1      102        1       0
```

And this is plotted like so:

```
plot_data = (df.value_counts()
   .sort_values(ascending=False)
   .reset_index()
   .drop_duplicates(['trajectory', 'segment'])
   .pivot_table(index='trajectory', columns='segment', values='prediction',))

cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(['c', 'b', 'g', 'y','m', ])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
sns.heatmap(plot_data,vmin=-0.5, vmax=4.5,cmap=cmap, annot=True)
```

Giving:

[image]

I want to fill all white cells to black. For that I have to replace all `NaN` values in my `plot_data` to some value, say `99`, and add black color code `k` to `cmap`.

```
plot_data = (df.value_counts()
   .sort_values(ascending=False)
   .reset_index()
   .drop_duplicates(['trajectory', 'segment'])
   .pivot_table(index='trajectory', columns='segment', values='prediction',
     fill_value=99))

cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(['c', 'b', 'g', 'y','m', 'k'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
sns.heatmap(plot_data,vmin=-0.5, vmax=4.5,cmap=cmap, annot=True)
```

And plot again, giviing:

[image]

**Confusion:** `4` is coloured `k: black`, same as `99`, instead of `m: magenta`. Plus, I do not like to annotate the null value cells with `99`. It is there as a placeholder, since I cannot plot when `NaN` values are replaced with character such as `-`.

Intended results:
something like the following

[image]

Comment: can you include the full code? even the call to plot

Comment: yes, this is added now.

Comment: I suspect the vmax is re-scaling and making the limits fuzzy. Try with no vmax, maybe that helps

Comment: with no `vmax` everything get messed up, resulting just 2 colours:`c` colour for all classes, `k`colour for `99`

Comment: yeah, then that's what needs to be fixed. If you fill with 5 instead of 99, and change vmax to 5 it should yield what you expect

Comment: I see. But I don't it annotated in the plot, just the black shading. I also don't like it to appear on the colorbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_bad`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_bad) to set the color for masked values of your colorbar to opaque black:

```
cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(['c', 'b', 'g', 'y','m',])
cmap.set_bad('k')
```

(in your colormap definition it's transparent black, that's why you can see the Axes patch in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, All I need was to set the background to black, before adding heatmap, like so:

```
ax.set_facecolor('black')
sns.heatmap(plot_data, vmin=-0.5, vmax=4.5,  cmap=cmap, annot=True)
```

And that's it.

Comment: While this works in the given situation, it's more like a workaround that works because the color value for missing values in your colormap is fully transparent. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73321317/3944322) for a more direct solution.